# Write a list comprehension to a file

Tags: list, haskell, file-io, list-comprehension

I generated a list of tupules using some function and list comprehension, like this

```
[(x,y, func (x,y)) | x<-[xmin,(xmin+dx)..xmax], y<-[ymin,(ymin+dy)..ymax]]
```

So I pretty much created a list of 3D coordinates of many points.

Now my question is, how do I efficiently write this list in a file? I need it to be something like,

```
x0 y0 z0
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write to a file, you could do something like:

```
main = do
    h <- openFile "output.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn h "Hello, file system"
    hClose h
```

A safer way might be to use `writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()`, which would close the handle if an error occurred, but you have to generate the entire contents first:

```
main = let contents = "Hello, " ++ "file" ++ " system"
       in writeFile "output.txt" contents
```

I'll let you decide which you want to use.  I would recommend the `writeFile` method because of its safety.

Next, I would look at `Data.List.intercalate`.  If you're coming from an imperative language like Python, you might be familiar with the string `join` method.  In Python:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(['Hello,', 'file', 'system']))
```

this would write the string `Hello, file system` to the file `output.txt`.  The `intercalate` function is very similar in Haskell:

```
main = writeFile "output.txt" $ intercalate " " ["Hello,", "file", "system"]
--         This is the string to join by ----^               ^
--         These are the strings being joined together ------|
```

Now all you need to do is figure out how to turn your data into strings in order to write it out to a file.  I would recommend writing a function

```
showTriple :: Show a => String -> (a, a, a) -> String
showTriple sep (x, y, z) = ???
```

which turns a triple into a `sep` delimited string.  That way you could easily swap that space out for a tab, comma, or whatever other symbol you might want to use.

If you get stuck, just edit your question with a progress update, showing your code and comment telling me what's got you stuck.

---

Now that you've solved the problem yourself, here's how I would do it using these functions:

```
-- This is just your list of data from above
range :: ((Double, Double) -> Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) -> [(Double, Double, Double)]
range func xs ys = [(x, y, func (x, y)) | x <- interval xs, y <- interval ys]
    where
        interval (tmin, tmax, dt)
            | tmin < tmax = [tmin, tmin+dt .. tmax] 
            | otherwise   = interval (tmax, tmin, dt)

writeDelimitedFile :: FilePath -> String -> [(Double, Double, Double)] -> IO ()
writeDelimitedFile file sep values = writeFile file $ delimitedString sep values

delimitedString :: String -> [(Double, Double, Double)] -> String
delimitedString sep values = intercalate "\n" $ map (showTriple sep) values

showTriple :: Show a => String -> (a, a, a) -> String
showTriple sep (x, y, z) = intercalate sep $ map show [x, y, z]

main :: IO ()
main = writeDelimitedFile "output.txt" " " $ range (uncurry (+)) (0, 10, 0.1) (0, 5, 0.1)
```

Of course, you could shorten it quite a bit without defining separate functions to do all the work and using `unwords` and `unlines` instead of `intercalate`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = writeFile "output.txt" $ unlines
        [unwords $ map show [x, y, z] |
            (x, y, z) <- range (uncurry (+)) (0, 10, 0.1) (0, 5, 0.1)]
```

But this makes it more difficult to change later.  And as you can see, if we want to keep it from marching off the side of the screen it has to be broken into multiple lines anyway.

Comment: @ysakamoto Also, look up the `lines` command for something like `lines . map (intercalate " ") . map showTriple`. A simple thing like this is super easy in Haskell.

Comment: I finally made it work! but I connected all these functions together and it got quite long... Is it a good practice for Haskell? Or should I split it into a few lines using some temporary variables?

Comment: Splitting things into manageable chunks is a good idea in any programming language. The tricky part is trying to pin down what "manageable" means. (And trying to spell that. I suck at spelling!)

Comment: @ysakamoto ssm has sent you down a handy path - `unlines`, `unwords`, `lines` and `words` are very useful.

Comment: @ysakamoto Don't use too many intermediate variables - `unwords.map show.toList $ t` is much nicer than `let xs = toList t` `bits = map show xs` `line = unwords bits`.

Comment: @ysakamoto Check my edits, it might give you an idea of how to shorten your code.

Comment: My approach is somewhat similar to your second one. I guess I need to learn different functions for different purposes. Thanks!